# Meaning of "on the wax" from an article in Stanford Encyclopedia of Philosophy

Tags: meaning, word-usage

I do not follow the meaning of "on the wax" below, and do not find its usage in any online dictionary. Yet [the original text](http://plato.stanford.edu/entries/plato-sophstate/) appears in Stanford Encyclopedia of Philosophy, thus peer-reviewed. So I suppose the usage is correct. Can anyone clarify the meaning of "on the wax"?

> The Sophist and Statesman are late Platonic dialogues, whose relative dates are established by their stylistic similarity to the Laws, a work that was apparently still **“on the wax”** at the time of Plato's death (Diogenes Laertius 3.37)

Comment: This is a complete guess (which is why this is a comment and not an answer), but it _could_ be the opposite of "on the wane," which would make it be similar in meaning to "on the rise" or "growing in strength."

Comment: @SomethingDark Thanks but the sentence does not sound correct if you put 'on the rise' in pace of 'on the wax'.

Comment: Were things written in wax in those days?  Just a guess.

Comment: Obviously, he had gone to the studio and cut the record, but the plates had not yet been made up to press the LP.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is obviously a reference to the wax tablets that were used for drafts and note-taking before the invention of paper; after you had made a fair copy onto a roll of papyrus, you could simply smooth over the wax tablet and re-use it.  Nowadays we would probably say 'in manuscript', but in ancient times, of course, all writing was in manuscript, so apparently the Stanford author thought this would be a clever alternative.

Comment: Though actually 'nowadays' we need another term for *in manuscript*, since nobody but fuddy-duddies prepares a rough draft on paper, and absolutely nobody prepares a handwritten draft.

Comment: I believe the standard expression is "on the books."

Comment: I agree with TimLymington. Nowadays, we say "in a draft state".

Comment: There is not much doubt that "was in the wax" has the standard and established meaning of "was growing" from the verb “to wax” = to grow. I can find no reference to wax tablets being used as jotters/notepads for a great work and the poster has given none. This seems to be a folk etymology.

Comment: @Greybeard The OP provides a citation to [Diogenes Laertius 3.37](http://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/text?doc=Perseus%3Atext%3A1999.01.0258%3Abook%3D3%3Achapter%3D1), which says "And according to Favorinus, when Plato read the dialogue *On the Soul*, Aristotle alone stayed to the end; the rest of the audience got up and went away. Some say that Philippus of Opus copied out the *Laws*, which were left upon waxen tablets, and it is said that he was the author of the Epinomis." So plainly wax was used by the Greeks for exactly this purpose.

Answer (score 3):

The reference in the Stanford article is to a statement made in Diogenes' Lives...

After doing a CTRL+F on the PDF from Project Gutenberg, this passage, located in book 3 (as per the Stanford ref) reads:
XXV. Aristotle says, that the treatises of Plato are something between poems and prose; and Phavorinus says, when Plato read his treatise on the Soul, Aristotle was the only person who sat it out, and that all the rest rose up and went away. And some say that Philip the Opuntian copied out the whole of his books upon Laws, **which were written on waxen tablets only.** Some people also attribute the Epinomis to him. Euphorion and Panætius have stated that the beginning of the treatise on the Republic was often altered and re-written; and that very treatise, Aristoxenus affirms, was found almost entire in the Contradictions of Protagoras; and that the first book he wrote at all was the Phædrus; and indeed that composition has a good many indications of a young composer. But Dicæarchus blames the whole style of that work as vulgar.

Comment: This supports the other answer, but please cite your source when not paraphrasing, and do go on to explain.  The block of text looks like a direct quote of the translation of Diogenes.  Check out how to [edit] your post and please visit the [help].

Answer (score 0):

For the benefit of others looking for the definition of "on the wax", although [TimLymington's](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/265898/3675) answer fits the usage in the question this phrase can also mean "on the rise" (as [SomethingDark](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/265896/meaning-of-on-the-wax-from-an-article-in-stanford-encyclopedia-of-philosophy#comment585126_265896) notes in their comment on the question).

The usage comes from the idiom "wax and wane". The [etymology](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/wax#Etymology_2) on Wiktionary has further info.